# Buttons going below screen in landscape mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am learning iphone app development and I am using swift. I took the lynda tutorial and I have created a very basic UI which is `View Controller` > `View` .
In the View I added a segmented control, two buttons(horizontal, facing each other), three `labels`, one textarea and two other `buttons`(horizontal, facing each other).

So I have these `UIcomponents` arranged vertically and I used 'Reset to suggested constraints' and made all the `buttons` equal width and equal height and everything is fine in potrait mode [image] but as soon as I go to landscape mode [image] the last two buttons disappear, if I add a constraint from bottom edges the whole UI gets messed up i.e. only one label and part of an upper button appears.

What should I do to make all the UI components visible both in potrait and landscape mode?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to go about this. I've set up a [github project](https://github.com/ezCoding/SVAutoLayoutExample) to show you one way to achieve it.

Short resume of what I did manually without the help of the `Interface Builder`:

- I've pinned the **segmented control** to the left, top and right of the parent view
- The **red button** below has a vertical constraint to the **segmented control** and a leading constraint to the parent view. It also als a horizontal space constraint to the **green button**
- The **green button** has a trailing constraint to the parent view, top aligned to the **red button** and widths set to equal to the **red button**.

This setup ensures, that the **segmented control** is responsible for specifying the distance to the top of the **parent view** and the **red button** specifies the width of itself and the **green button** (test it, by changing the value of the horizontal space constraint)

I've turned the same principle upside down. So the views in the bottom are always pinned to the bottom. But as I said, there are many ways to achieve this. You could also create 3 container views for the elements in the top, center and bottom and pin those to the top, center and bottom.

The running app looks like this:[image]

[image]

Comment: Your project is in ipad, if I run my project in ipad, I am getting the correct layout. The problem is in the iphones, in every iphone I have different layout issues, its frustrating. I am trying to debug. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. If the layout doesn't fit, because it is too large, you might consider using a `UIScrollView`

Comment: My answer (and github project) shows you how to pin Views to the bottom/top/center of the view. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have been trying for last two days what you suggested and it fixes the UI in one iphone model but with another model the UI is completely messed up.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to display your content differently in landscape mode, it is possible (and most likely preferable) to create an alternate landscape interface.

Quoting the Apple developer's page on the subject:

"To support an alternate landscape interface, you must do the following:

1. Implement two view controller objects. One to present a portrait-only
   interface, and the other to present a landscape-only interface.
2. Register for the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification notification.
   In your handler method, present or dismiss the alternate view controller based on the current device orientation."

For more information about this, check out this apple developer page and scroll down to "creating an alternate landscape interface".

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Comment: Thanks, I read the guide. Right now I am trying to understand how to do layout, I dont want to create different layouts for different mode. But the guide was definitely helpful and useful.